# How do I set variable equal to the amount lines of strings that I have in my text doc for Java?

Tags: java, string, variables

I am putting together strings such as:

spagetti

Spinich

cheese

etc down the list in a text doc, how can I assign each a specified variable that I can call from in eclipse ?

like calling spagetti as “1” or “1a”

I am new at java and would like to know

All I have right now is

```
{

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileAccess {

    private static String fileName = "ingredients";

    private static Scanner inputStream = null;

}

}
```

Comment: not sure what you are meaning, but maybe you are thinking of an Array?

Comment: Based on the title, you want to count the number of lines in the file and store into a variable?

Comment: javascript !== java

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/2310289

Comment: @Dummy Yah, like assign each line on the text with a certain variable, there is about 30 of them so I can call them through an object

Comment: try a String array like `String [] strArray` where `strArray[0]` will be your first String

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("path/to/your/file");
String[] lines = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath)
                      .lines()
                      // discard lines that only contain whitespaces
                      .filter(line -> !line.matches("^\\s+$")
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

So now you can access the first line as `lines[0]`, second line as `lines[1]`, etc.

Or traverse the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
```

Or use for-each loop

```
for (String line: lines)
    System.out.println(line);
```